# Insert multiple generated value into table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

First thing, my question is quite complicated and I am not really proficient to explain it in details, so I would like to say sorry in advance.

Ok, here is the thing. I execute this query

```
string count = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Student WHERE IntakeID = 'MYVALUE'"
```

And it would return the number of **10**. So I continue with this code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(count, conn);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
for (int x = 0; x < temp; x++)
{
     string query = "INSERT INTO Docket (DocketNo, StudentID) VALUES ('" + getUniqueKey() + "','(SELECT StudentID FROM Student WHERE IntakeID = 'MYVALUE')')
}
```

PS: getUniqueKey() is a method to get my generated unique key.

Is this piece of code technically correct? The result I want to have is something like below:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| DocketNo  | StudentID   |
+-----------+-------------+
| 18590394  | TP123456    |
| 09141563  | TP012457    |
| 58293495  | TP049185    |
+-----------+-------------+
```

If you are unclear of my question, I will try my best to make it clearer. Sorry for inconvenience.

**UPDATE (ANSWER):**
With the help from Paparazzi (Thanks!) for his code, I modified and come up with my own solution.

```
string count = "SELECT StudentID FROM Student WHERE IntakeID = 'MYVALUE'"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(count, conn);
string query = "INSERT INTO Docket (DocketNo, StudentID) VALUES ";
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        var loop = true;
        while (loop)
        {
            loop = rdr.Read();
            if (!loop)
            {
             //When end of rows and no more data to be retrieve, it removes the last "," from  the query.
                char[] trimChar = { ',' };
                string newQuery = query.TrimEnd(trimChar);
                cmd.CommandText = newQuery;
            }
            else { 
                query += "('" + GetUniqueKey() + "','" + rdr.GetString(0) + "')";
                query += ",";
            }
            
        }
    }
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

So actually while looping on the SqlDataReader, the query would generate in the background something like:

```
INSERT INTO  Docket(DocketNo, StudentID) VALUES ('1562456','TP028800'), ('1465446','TP028801'),..........('4939104','TP028810'),
```

Take note there will be a "," comma at the end of the query because of the `query += ",";`. And when the SqlDataReader returns no more rows, it would execute the `if(!loop)` statement to remove the last "," (comma) from the query.

If you are unclear what is the `+=` for, read more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx

**UPDATE 2:**
@Paparazzi has come up with a much more efficient and performance-wise method if you are managing a huge data. Look for his code in his own post. :)

Comment: Use parameters instead of concatenating strings and you should explain better how the 'MYVALUE' changes. This is probably a key point

Comment: @Steve Your concern on using parameters instead of concatenating strings is because of SQL injection right? 'MYVALUE' is just a value i get from my DropDownList which i coded it as `" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string count = "SELECT StudentID FROM Student WHERE IntakeID = 'MYVALUE'"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(count, conn);
string query = "INSERT INTO Docket (DocketNo, StudentID) VALUES ";
conn.Open();
bool first = true;
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        if (first)
          first = false;
        else 
           query += ", "
        query += "('" + getUniqueKey() + "', '" + rdr.GetString(0) + "')";  
    }
}
if (!first)
{
    cmd.CommandText = query + ";";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
conn.Close();
```

StringBuilder is faster than += on string
And multiple values is limited to 1000 (I think) but WAY more efficient than individual inserts
So if you can get more than 1000 then need to add a counter and fire off the insert

```
string getID = "SELECT StudentID FROM Student WHERE IntakeID = 'MYVALUE'"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getID , conn);
string insert = "INSERT INTO Docket (DocketNo, StudentID) VALUES ";
Int32 count = 0;
StringBuiler sb = new StringBuiler();
conn.Open();    
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        if (count == 0)
        { 
            sb.Clear();
            sb.AppendLine(insert);
        }
        else 
           sb.Append(", ")
        sb.Append("('" + getUniqueKey() + "', '" + rdr.GetString(0) + "')");
        count++;
        if(count > 800)
        {
            count = 0;
            cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString() + ";";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            // most likely need a separate cmd here has a open reader 
            // will leave that as an exercise for you 
            // could even go asynch if you want to get faster
            // or you could just build up multiple inserts on sb 
        }  
    }
}
if (count > 0)
{
    cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString() + ";";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know the results after I try it

Comment: I've modify some of your code as it has some minor error but it still doesn't work. I'm not sure have I missed out something or what. It gives me the error of **"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."** when it reaches the line of `query += "('" + getUniqueKey() + "','" + rdr.GetString(0) + "')";`

Comment: @ChuahChengJun Yes there was a big hole.  I was writing from memory.  Will update.

Comment: Hello, I managed to come up with my own solution with the help of your code. Thanks alot man!

Comment: I get you wrote your own *equivalent* code but don't you think this answer of simply not add the comma in the first place is cleaner and more efficient?  And with an open Reader I think that ExecuteNonQuery will fail.

Comment: Hmm sorry, I don't get it, what you mean by "not adding the comma in the first place is clearner and more efficient?" I am aware of with an open reader it might fails the ExecuteNonQuery method but it appears to be working in my code, at least without any bugs or errors so far. Correct me if I'm wrong, `sb.Append(", ")` then `sb.Append("('" + getUniqueKey() + "', '" + rdr.GetString(0) + "')");` won't the query generates something like `INSERT INTO Docket(DocketNo,StudentID) VALUES , ('2131231','TP012443')` ? Isn't invalid to have a comma after the `VALUES` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(count, conn);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
for (int x = 0; x < temp; x++)
{
     string query += "INSERT INTO Docket (DocketNo, StudentID) VALUES ('" + getUniqueKey() + "','(SELECT StudentID FROM Student WHERE IntakeID = 'MYVALUE')');";


}
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Doesn't work as `string query +=` as += is an invalid expression term

Comment: Even if you fix the += that is not a valid insert.